# Boundness of Riemann zeta by log function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

[image]

In the picture above it states that for $Re(s)>1$ we have that lower bound of a is $\leq 0$, and it claims that it is obvious from Dirichlet series of $\log\varsigma(s)=\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^slog(n)}$.
I dont see how it follows from it :/ Can anyone clerify this?

Comment: Not sure, but isn’t the series absolutely convergent? And changing the imaginary part of $s$ just changes the arguments of the terms so $\log{\zeta}$ is bounded on the vertical lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $s=\sigma+it$, so that

$$
|\log\zeta(s)|\le\sum_{n\ge2}{\Lambda(n)\over n^\sigma\log n}\le\zeta(\sigma)
$$

Since the RHS converges whenever $\sigma>1$, we conclude that $\nu(\sigma)\le0$ for $\sigma>1$.